# ayuda con preventDefault en envio de formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

hola necesito de su ayuda ya que estoy intentando enviar un formulario mediante ajax y al momento de hacerlo me redirecciona con la funcion action del form, dicho formulario esta dentro de un modal, y el ajax se encuentra en un archivo .js al cual se hace referencia en mi archivo index.php, este es el codigo de mi ajax

```css
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#next").on("click",function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

     var btnEnviar = $("#next");
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
             
                btnEnviar.val("Enviando"); // Para input de tipo button
                btnEnviar.attr("disabled","disabled");
            },
            complete:function(data){
              
                btnEnviar.val("Enviar formulario");
                btnEnviar.removeAttr("disabled");
            },
            success: function(data){
                
                $(".respuesta").html(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
               
                alert("Problemas al tratar de enviar el formulario");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

nota: si agrego mi codigo en el archivo que contiene el modal lo ejecuta sin problemas, el problema se presenta ya que lo trato de ejecutar desde un archivo javascript
si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria...

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías añadir el código HTML del formulario? Especialemente interesa ver cómo es el botón con `id="next"`.

Comment: claro que si el codigo del boton es el siguiente:
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger cerrar" id="next">Siguiente</button>

Comment: Tienes un botón de tipo submit al que al hacer click, dispara dos eventos, onSubmit y onClick. En tu caso quieres que onSubmit no haga nada, pero el preventDefault se lo estás haciendo al evento onClick. Lo puedes resolver de varias maneras, y aunque seguro que alguien te responde rápidamente, te animo a que te adelantes y lo intentes resolver tú porque ya estás muy cerca de la solución. Mira también lo que pasaría si al final del evento devuelves return false.

Comment: lo he intentado con los dos eventos submit y click pero no me funcionan desde elarchivo js, si añado una etiqueta script donde se encuentra el modal lo ejecuta sin problema alguno, tambien he intentado un return false en ves del preventdefault pero me sigue redireccionando, aun sigo intentando varias formas de solucionarlo .

Comment: Puedes añadir el código html de tu app?

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar que te redireccione al recurso al que haces referencia con tu formulario

suponiendo que el id de tu formulario es `form`

```
form.addEventListener("submit",function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  //lo que necesites hacer
})
```

Comment: ya lo intente amigo y me sigue redireccionando a mi php...